# wordpress plugin help

Tags: wordpress, plugins, sef

I have created a plugin where I am passing a variable through the url. The variable is the id of an item from the database. In the database I have a stored search engine friendly field that I could use to set the url but am lost as to how to do it. Example of the db:

```
id     sef           name
1      dogs-name     Dog's Name
```

Now when I am passing the variable in the url I am passing it by doing:

```
<a href="current-url/?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Link</a>
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
<a href="current-url/<?php echo $sef;?>">Link</a>
```

This would make for a much nicer url. However when I do that it doesnt work because wordpress is sending me to the 404 page. Does anyone know if this is possible and can give me an example of how to do it? I looked into the pretty permalinks stuff but only found how to rewrite the urls made in wordpress and not coming from a plugin that is created. Is there a way to possibly add a variable for replacement through wordpress to be rewritten?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these links help?

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-an-extra-parameter-in-an-url

http://youngdutchdesign.com/rewrite-multiple-get-variables-for-wordpress-plugins